# JSON data not appending properly to table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table, append

I am creating a table by extracting values from different JSON urls. For the first JSONUrl (PoolsUrl), everything works fine. Apppending the same table with data from the second JSON Url (RoundsUrl) does not go propery. Correct data is returned but appended in the last row of the table (see picture below). The RoundsUrl is created using JSON values from the PoolsUrl.

**Why is the data for the 'Created Rounds' column appended in the last row as shown in picture below?**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
my_pools = {}   
$.getJSON(PoolsUrl,
        function (json) {
            my_pools = json;
            createdRounds = {}
            my_pools.createdRounds = {
                "CreatedRounds": "none"
            } //created this key and value to add number of rounds in the pool JSON properties.
            var tr;
            for (var i = 0; i < my_pools.length; i++) {
                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<td>" + my_pools[i].poolId + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + my_pools[i].name + "</td>");
                tr.append("<td>" + my_pools[i].totTeams + "</td>");
                my_poolIdString = my_pools[i].poolId.toString()
                RoundsUrl = url +  my_poolIdString
                $.getJSON(RoundsUrl, //output: {"1":"Round 1","2":"Round 2"}
                    function (json) {
                        my_roundsCreated = json;
                        my_roundsCount = Object.keys(my_roundsCreated).length
                        my_pools.createdRounds = my_roundsCount;
                        tr.append("<td>" + my_pools.createdRounds + "</td>")
                    })
                $('table').append(tr);
                }
            })
});
```

PoolsUrl and RoundsUrl themselves are left out here but these work properly. JSON values are returned.

The issue might be that the variable 'my_pools.createdRounds' in the second $.getJSON function does not refer to my global my_pools object.

Output table image:

[image: Why is "rounds created"column not appended properly?]

Comment: probably because it is asynchronous....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the fact that you have an asynchronous call. The variable `tr` is shared and by the time the call comes back, the tr is a different element.

Move the tr declaration inside the for loop.

```
var tr = $('<tr/>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @epascarello. Your suggestion did solve the problem. Nothing changed.

Comment: Your comment makes no sense. It says it solved your issue, but it did not. So did you declare it inside so the variable is no longer shared?

Comment: ai that was a painful typo, your suggestion did NOT solve the issue. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: my page is loading very slowly due to the synchronous call. Would you know why I am stil getting a async call when i declare the var tr within the for loop?